# Should we use 'mint' or 'minting' as a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Most of the existing questions use 'mint', but 'mint' is a verb whereas 'minting' is a noun. If tags are topics and topics should be nouns, then 'minting' should be used, but 'mint' is shorter. Do we have a convention to keep tags as short as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "minting" is appropriate.

Minting is the infinitive version of the word as opposed to minted (past) mint (present) and will mint (future)